# Vuetify: autocomplete components unable to build as the expected

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Now I want to build a autocomplete box but I'm unable to build as the image shown below. Please help me to fix this. THe default value for the room is 1 and the column should be allowed user to click on the option but not allowed them to type. Thank you.

```
 <v-autocomplete
    v-model="room"
    :items="rooms"
    label="room"
 ></v-autocomplete>

data() {
    return {
      rooms: ['1 Room', '2 Rooms', '3 Rooms'],
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `v-select` is a better component to use if the user shouldn't be able to type anything in the selection box. The [v-select API documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots) lists a   `selection` slot to customize the appearance of the selected item. Using this slot you can choose to show only the first character, which matches your requirements for "1 Room" to display as "1".

```html
<template>
  <v-select v-model="tempForm.roomCMS" :items="rooms" outlined label="Rooms">
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
      {{ item.charAt(0) }}
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tempForm: {
        roomCMS: 1
      },
      rooms: ['1 Room', '2 Rooms', '3 Rooms', '4 Rooms', '5 Rooms', '6 Rooms', '7 Rooms', '8 Rooms']
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/wvXVZBQ)